# Should graphic novels be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Assuming the question isn't breaking any other rules, should questions about graphic novels/comic books be on-topic for this site?

On one hand, comic-books are books just like any other books. On the other hand, because of the nature of comic books they're much more likely to be about Sci-Fi topics, like spaceships, superheros, and magic, so they might be better on [Scifi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/). (Although that doesn't make them *off-topic* per se)

Should we allow questions about comic-books?

Comment: I suggest you change *comic books* to *graphic novels*. For instance Frank Miller, Neil Gaiman. Not the serialised stuff that has +100 issues, but the series that are coherent and complete.

Comment: @gallifreian Good idea! Done.

Comment: Why not?........

Comment: "Assuming, its on-topic, should it be on-topic?"

Comment: Just to make sure, in the sense you ask, are Erich Kastner's children's novels eg. *Der kleine Mann* graphic novels? Or Roald Dahl's *Matilda*?  These novels have drawings some of which are just for illustration, but a few show essential details that aren't mentioned in the text.

Answer (score 30):

I think they should be On-Topic.  There can be quite extensive character analysis, plot explanation, etc. related to comics that would add quality content to the site.  AND, not all comics fall into the sci-fi/fantasy umbrella of sff.se, so we can offer a home to those that don't already.

Answer (score 19):

I think they should be on-topic.

There's a [masters thesis](https://scholarworks.iupui.edu/bitstream/handle/1805/898/Frank%2520Miller's%2520Heroism%2520Pdf,%2520Unsigned%2520(Jones).pdf?sequence=6) on Frank Miller's *Sin City*. [Another thesis](http://digitalcommons.liberty.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1282&context=honors) on Alan Moore's *Watchmen*, not to mention a [whole book](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470396857.html) titled *Watchmen and Philosophy: A Rorschach Test*. A thesis on *The Killing Joke* [is present](https://www.academia.edu/11310456/The_Killing_Joke_The_Jokers_Laughter_and_Resistance_in_Comics_and_Films) as well.

Surely, not all graphic novels live up to the standards of the mentioned works. Yet, it is entirely possible to analyze them in the same way we'd analyze a book.

Answer (score 14):

**Yes, because they are literature.**

Of course, this is debatable, but since [Maus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maus) has [won a pulitzer](http://www.theplaidzebra.com/graphic-novel-to-ever-win-a-pulitzer-prize/), it's pretty clear, that comics are being considered literature and so are manga. Which makes them *on-topic*. On the other hand are there other SE's dealing with these contents ([Sci-fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) or [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/)), which I dont think is a problem, if someone decides to ask about literature, they should be able to do it here.

I think that graphic novels are on-topic.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this argument. Bob Dylan won the Nobel Prize for Literature. Does that make all songs literature?

Comment: YES! Songs, poems ARE literature. I agree on the Bob Dylan part tho... :)

Comment: @HDE226868 Just Sondheim :-)

Comment: He won a pulitzer as well^.  Songs, muscials, stage plays are literature.

Answer (score -17):

I think they should be on-topic when they don't have fantastic elements.

If they have fantastic elements (magic, SF, antropomorphic animals...), they they belong on SF&F SE.

If they are set in the real world, either today's world or historical stories, then they don't belong on SF&F SE. I'd like to give them a home here. Series like "XIII" or "Largo Winch" can generate good questions, that aren't really on-topic elsewhere.

Comment: Sites are allowed to overlap. Carving out a special "as long as they aren't already on topic on SFF" really isn't appropriate. That'd be like M&TV saying "ask about all M&TV that isn't SFF"... we just don't work that way.

Comment: Sorry, -1. SFF and Literature are separate sites, and overlap is perfectly fine. **Questions about literary works of sci-fi or fantasy should be on-topic on both.** See also [this meta question](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/q/4/17).

Comment: On a side note, anthropomorphic animals [aren't enough to make something on-topic for SFF](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5119/31394).

Comment: @Randal'Thor but _Ratatoille_ slipped anyway _<grins>_