# Are comic identifications on topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope, story-identification

1. Are comic-identification questions on-topic? (I [asked one](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/finding-comic-referenced-in-semi-classic-physics-problem), and created a tag for it - should it be tagged story-identification?)
2. When tagging comics, should we have a tag for the writer and a tag for the illustrator and a tag for the title? (What I did when tagging.)

Comment: You're asking to identify a comic yet you already use an author tag, implying you already know the author. If you don't, please don't use them.

Comment: @Gallifreyan as I'm asking for the identification of a specific comic within the Superman universe, and these comics were collectively written by a known author, according to wikipedia, I assumed that was alright...

Comment: Not all Superman comics are written by the same author. They may have been created by a person, but a whole bunch of writers and artists have worked on them since. Unless you're sure it belongs to one writer, you shouldn't use the author tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proposal: rename \[story-identification\] to \[identification-request\]](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1481/proposal-rename-story-identification-to-identification-request)

Answer (score 6):

1. Story identification questions are [on-topic](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/17), and comics are [on-topic](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33/17), so comic identification questions should certainly be on-topic. I would, however, tag them with [story-identification](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) rather than creating a new comic identification tag. The skills required to identify a comic are much the same as those required to identify any other kind of story, so it makes sense to group all these identification requests together under a single tag.

Comment: I have done so.

Answer (score 4):

2. Personally, I only use the author tag I see most relevant. E.g. when asking about the story, I use the writer tag. When asking about the art, or the lettering, I use another tag.

   For the titles - our [last ruling](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/737/11) (though still a bit inconclusive IMO) seems to be in favour of title tags. Please note that it's better to use a franchise (or book series or universe) tag when the work is a part of one (though I'm unsure if we need to group all comics about a superhero like this and this needs a separate discussion).

That said, you have to be 100% sure to add the name of the author to a [story-identification](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) question. Unless you're asking for a specific story by a specific author, better just note in the question *"I think it's a story by X"*.