# Does this stack accept requests for identifying short stories?

Tags: discussion

Does this stack accept posts requesting assistance in identifying the title of a particular short story?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are comic identifications on topic?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/845/are-comic-identifications-on-topic) (I know it's for comics and not short stories but the fans logic applies: since both halves of "short story" "identification" are on-topic, the whole is as well)

Comment: We have [142 questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request+short-stories) tagged with both [tag:identification-request] and [tag:short-stories].